# Spark ML Logistic Regression in Python: Set the model threshold to maximize F-Measure

Tags: apache-spark, classification, logistic-regression, prediction, threshold

I've trained a logistic regression in Spark using pipeline. It ran and I am looking at model diagnostics.

I created my model summary (lr_summary = lrModel.stages[-1].summary).
After that I pretty much copied the code from [this webpage](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html#binomial-logistic-regression). It all works until I try to determine the best threshold based on F-measure using this example Python code:

```
# Set the model threshold to maximize F-Measure
fMeasure = lr_summary.fMeasureByThreshold
maxFMeasure = fMeasure.groupBy().max('F-Measure').select('max(F-Measure)').head()
bestThreshold = fMeasure.where(fMeasure['F-Measure'] == maxFMeasure['max(F-Measure)']).select('threshold').head()['threshold']
lr.setThreshold(bestThreshold)
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an error in line 3 (bestThreshold = ):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Any advice?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this problem, but it is possible that model doesn't have summary (in that case I would expect attribute error in `maxFMeasure = ...` line). You can check if model has one:

```
lrModel.stages[-1].hasSummary
```

Also you can make this code much simpler:

```
bestThreshold = fMeasure.orderBy(fMeasure['F-Measure'].desc()).first().threshold
```

Comment: My model does have summary. As I mentioned above, I successfully implement all the earlier rows of the code on that web page, e.g.: 'lr_summary.roc.show()'. However, your code DID work. So, thank you so much!